# MysQL multiple foreign keys: error number 150

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I cannot create this table due to a foreign key error. The error message is:

> Can't create table 'CHECKERS.MOVEPOSITION' (errno: 150)

```
CREATE TABLE CHECKERS.MOVEPOSITION (
  moveposition_id int NOT NULL auto_increment,
  game_id int NOT NULL,
  participant_id int NOT NULL,
  square_id int NOT NULL,
  move_type_id int NOT NULL,
  move_order varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  from_position varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  to_position varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (moveposition_id),
  FOREIGN KEY (square_id) REFERENCES PIECE (square_id),
  FOREIGN KEY (participant_id) REFERENCES PARTICIPANT (participant_id)
);
```

I'm wondering if someone used to creating tables with multiple foreign keys could help?

Comment: mysql (actually almost all rdbms ) does support multiple foreign keys, do you have referenced tables in place when run this create statement?

Comment: Are you using the same `ENGINE`, `COLLATION`, `DATA TYPE` and `CHARSET` for all tables?

Comment: Please read about [mcve] for the future.